# iPhone 5 : Is my phone normal or not?

Tags: ios, hardware, iphone

Please anyone help me, especially expert on iPhone and iPhone 5 or iPhone 5 user.
                My iPhone is second handed, I don't know this thing is normal or not

1. Fully charge about 2 hours 15 minutes
2. Battery usage just 6 hours that I use for camera (full hours with airplane mode), and about 2 days (40 hours) with 3g (sometimes use WiFi) with minimal use (just open whatsapp and instagram for a while)
3. It's easy to warm if I use more than 5 minutes, and easy to cold too.
4. Touch responsivity in corner screens is less (only touch action), but it still works and smooth for scrolling or touch a large button

Please anyone help me, Suggestions and feedbacks are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your iPhone 5 is in good condition. Your charging speed seem to be similar to other iPhone 5 data. Charging should take around 3 hours. They have a fast charge function till 80% and they'll start filling up slowly.

However, your battery might be a little lesser than expected of a new iPhone. All lithium-ion batteries lose a little amount of capability of holding the energy. They are called charge cycles and commonly, the Lithium-Ion battery degrades to around 80% when charged 300-500 times.

Your iPhone is perfectly normal :D!!

Learn how to maximize your battery performance:
http://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/
Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5568093?start=0&tstart=0